# How to select row with exactly only 2 unique value with tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rowwise

What I have:

```r
library(magrittr)
set.seed(1234)
what_i_have <- tibble::tibble(
    A = c(0, 1) |> sample(5, replace = TRUE),
    B = c(0, 1) |> sample(5, replace = TRUE),
    C = c(0, 1) |> sample(5, replace = TRUE)
)
```

It looks like this:

```r
> what_i_have
# A tibble: 5 x 3
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1
2     1     0     1
3     1     0     1
4     1     0     0
5     0     1     1
```

What I want:

```r
what_i_want <- what_i_have %>% .[apply(., 1, function(row) row |> unique() |> length() == 2),]
```

It looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     0     1
2     1     0     1
3     1     0     0
4     0     1     1
```

My question is: **is there a `tidyverse` way to do the things above?**

I tried this:

```r
what_i_have |> 
    dplyr::rowwise() |> 
    dplyr::filter_all(function(row) row |> unique() |> length() == 2)
```

but it returns the following empty `tibble` and I do not know why

```
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# Rowwise: 
# … with 3 variables: A <dbl>, B <dbl>, C <dbl>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`. Here, I treat each row as a vector (via `c_across`), then get the number of distinct values using `n_distinct` and return `TRUE` for the rows that have 2 unique values.

```
library(tidyverse)

what_i_have %>%
  rowwise %>%
  filter(n_distinct(c_across(everything())) == 2)
```

**Output**

```
      A     B     C
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     1     1
2     1     0     1
3     1     0     0
4     1     1     0
```

A mixed method approach with `apply` could be:

```
what_i_have %>% 
  filter(apply(., 1, \(x)length(unique(x)))==2)
```

**Data**

```
what_i_have  <-
  structure(
    list(
      A = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1),
      B = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
      C = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0)
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-5L)
  )
```

Comment: I believe `rowwise` should be `rowwise()`?

Comment: @ChrisLAM You can write it either way. Both ways will group the `data.frame` by row. I just prefer to eliminate any unnecessary characters when I can.